# subquery or condition not working

Tags: mysql, database

in my project i want to execute this type of query but it returns error so please help me. i want this type of query to be execute.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    company_details
WHERE
    com_id NOT IN (SELECT com_id FROM com_size)
OR (SELECT com_id FROM com_cat)
```

above query returns error and i want com_id that is in company_details but not in com_size or com_cat table.and i also try this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    company_details
LEFT JOIN com_size ON com_size.com_id != company_details.com_id
LEFT JOIN com_cat ON com_cat.com_id != company_details.com_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  You should probably use `not exists` rather than `not in`:

```
select cd.*
from company_details cd
where not exists (select 1 from com_size cs where cs.com_id = cd.com_id) and
      not exists (select 1 from com_cat cc where cc.com_id = cd.com_id);
```

The reason `not exists` is better is because of how it handles `NULL` values in the subquery:  if any of the values are `NULL`, then all comparisons fail (either "false" or `NULL`).

As an added bonus, `not exists` is often faster in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from company_details 
where 
    com_id not in (select com_id from com_size) AND 
    com_id not in (select com_id from com_cat)
```